# SQL join and merge Quest

Tags: sql

I have got problem, like this on picture. When I join other table it makes multiple records. How to get one record, merge languages and show them in one cell?

[image: SQL JOIN]
I want to do something like this [image]

Comment: which in the language field do you want to show, or if not at all

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you really need the query to output a series of comma-delimited strings directly, or do you just want each country's list of languages to appear that way in a report generated by some other software that queries your database? If it's the latter, it may be that the other software is the more natural place to perform that aggregation. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got answer by myself but anyway thanks for helping @MichaelEvanchik!

```
SELECT CountryCode, group_concat( Language ) AS Language 
FROM countrylanguage 
GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Here you go [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9cf4/2/0). Without learning tsql :D

Comment: next time let the community know which version of sql server you are using.

Mine works for your data under TSQL (MSSQL), there is no group_concat in TSQL, i think thats why all the negative voting

Comment: also above you only have 1 table, coultrylanguage,  where is country?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/381ef/2  this is mine with the two tables you started out with, so i do not think you solved the problem you asked

Comment: I know i changed when I noticed that I have a bad tag and server-sql is something else. I just added everything behind join and it works like yours now. Sorry for bad tag again :'(

Answer (score 2):

here you go,  (oh and thanks for the negative vote on previous attempt above cause you want stack overflow to do work for you)

```
;WITH All_Data AS
(
   select  c.code, c.country, c.continent, c.region, l.language
from country c inner join countrylanguage l on l.code = c.code
)

SELECT distinct a.code, a.country, a.continent, a.region

    ,STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + CAST(B.language AS VARCHAR)
           FROM All_Data B
            WHERE A.code = B.code
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS D


FROM All_Data A
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/381ef/2

worked for me in my test tables, please in the future use sqlfiddle so the a community member doesn't have to create a development environment to solve the problem

Comment: Yep I wanted to vote negative on post because, I can't vote negative on comments "have fun learning tsql" :)

Comment: You can see my results in comment :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a one to many issue on your join  (language has multiple entries)

pretty hard to do in one statement, you can work with this, or use a cursor or while loop, we are not here to code for you

```
DECLARE @languages VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @languages = COALESCE(@languages + ', ', '') + c.code + ' ' + Name 
from country c inner join countrylanguage on l.code = c.code

select distinct c.country, c.continent, c.region, @languages 
from country c 
left join countrylanguage cl on cl.countrycode = c.code
```

Comment: It's still not what i want. I want to do my country in one record. And there i want to get field what show all languages after comma